# In Java What is the < > notation

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does Map<?, ?> mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777936/what-does-map-mean-in-java)
>   [Java Generics - What is this syntax for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238150/java-generics-what-is-this-syntax-for)

I was wondering what does the notation `< >` does in Java, for example.

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase 
    implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
```

I am not a java expert in any fashion. I hope you can provide some clear answer for the reasons behind using the `< >` notation.

Comment: You might want to read that -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: They are related to `Generic`. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Comment: What directive is used to justify so many down votes for this sort of newbie question?

Comment: @EricLeschinski Downvoting because a person using Hadoop Interface and don't know generics.. Not the hello world program...

Comment: Your specific line of code is for a inner class, which uses `MapReduceBase` as base class and which implements `Mapper`. Mapper has multiple generic types defined, but this specific `Map` only implements the methods for the types `LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable`. The inner class is static, i.e. it cannot access fields of an instance of the outer class.

Comment: @ZEROMILE i learn java when java was 1.2 versions old and then i ran a 10 year career run with PHP. I just got back to Java and was reading some code and had a question. I belive SO is here to be helpful place for the dev community but natzis like the downvotes who jumping up and ego-tripping aint really helping the cause. What would it matter even if i pulled up some code from dalvikvm if the question is real why does it matter to others.

Comment: @EricLeschinski Thanks for supportive comment, see my comment above for some explanation. This very first question of mine has cost me the ability to ask questions here.

Comment: @DevZer0 https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java+generics  The very first link and in 3rd page, you will find the meaning of <>. Just google it before posting a question for which answer already exists.

Comment: @ZEROMILE my point is if i don't know the word generics how do i go search about it because < > stands for less than and greater than also. so i didn't figure out a best way to search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It denotes generics. `Mapper` is a generic and you're inheriting from `Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>`, which is that generic specialized for those types.

It's like `Vector` - also a generic - you can have `Vector<Object>` and `Vector<SomeOtherClass>`.